# Best way to setup locomotivejs with passport-twitter?

Tags: node.js, twitter-oauth, passport.js, locomotivejs

I'm trying to configure passport-twitter in my locomotive project.

The problem is that nothing happens after hitting the /auth/twitter url.

Edit: I hit the controller but twitter seems to not be invoked.

What I did was set a match to /auth/twitter at routes.js and mapped this to an auth_controller.js

Something like the code below:

- routes.js

  ```
  this.match('auth/twitter/', 'auth#twitter');

  this.match('auth/twitter/callback/', 'auth#callback');
  ```
- auth_controller.js

  ```
   var locomotive = require('locomotive')
  , Controller = locomotive.Controller
  , passport = require('passport');

  var AuthController = new Controller();

  AuthController.twitter = function() {

  console.log('[##] AuthController.twitter [##]');     

  passport.authenticate('twitter'), function(req, res) {};  
  }

  AuthController.callback = function() {
  console.log('[##] AuthController.callback [##]');

  passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/show' }),
    function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('/list');
    };    
   } 

  module.exports = AuthController;
  ```

I really don't know if that's the right way to use it with locomotive, any help will be very appreciated.

Cheers,
Fabio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Passport needs to be configured first. An example on how to do that can be found [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/blob/master/examples/signin/app.js). In the case of LocomotiveJS, the obvious place of putting that configuration would be an initializer:

```
// config/initializers/10_passport_twitter.js <-- you can pick filename yourself
module.exports = function(done) {    
  // At least the following calls are needed:
  passport.use(new TwitterStrategy(...));
  passport.serializeUser(...);
  passport.deserializeUser(...);
};
```

Next, configure sessions and initialize Passport:

```
// config/environments/all.js
module.exports = {
  ...
  // Enable session support.
  this.use(connect.cookieParser());
  this.use(connect.session({ secret: YOUR_SECRET }));
  // Alternative for the previous line: use express.cookieSession() to enable client-side sessions
  /*
    this.use(express.cookieSession({
     secret  : YOUR_SECRET,
     cookie  : {
       maxAge  : 3600 * 6 * 1000 // expiry in ms (6 hours)
     }
    }));
  */

  // Initialize Passport.
  this.use(passport.initialize());
  this.use(passport.session());
  ...
};
```

Next, configure routes:

```
// config/routes.js
this.match('auth/twitter/', 'auth#twitter');
this.match('auth/twitter/callback/', 'auth#callback');
```

Because `passport.authenticate` is middleware, it's easier to use a `before` hook in your controller:

```
// app/controllers/auth_controller.js
...
AuthController.twitter = function() {
  // does nothing, only a placeholder for the following hook.
};
AuthController.before('twitter', passport.authenticate('twitter'));

AuthController.callback = function() {
  // This will only be called when authentication succeeded.
  this.redirect('/list');
}
AuthController.before('callback', passport.authenticate('twitter', { failureRedirect: '/auth/twitter' })};
```

Disclaimer: I haven't tested the code above, I'm basing it on my own code which I recently used in a project, and which uses `passport-local` instead of `passport-twitter`. However, the basics are pretty much similar, apart from the callback-URL which isn't needed for `passport-local`.

Comment: Perfect! Reviewing the code I realize some misconfiguration issues at the passport initializer, and the 'hooks' you suggested worked like a charm!! Thanks!!

Comment: Thank you. @robertklep: Could you please provide us the "version" with passport-local? I didn't get it :(

Comment: @TobiasOberrauch this particular project used passport-local v0.1.6. I see that it went to 1.0.0 a few months ago, not sure what the differences are between those two versions.